# Should I downvote an answer that might be generally correct, but is wrong for my question?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

Looking at [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027682/how-to-mount-a-cd-with-qnx-on-a-virtual-machine), the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33039569/4872477) posted seems perfectly fine. It might be correct in general, but in my specific instance it is incorrect (I tried it and it didn't work, and eventually got official support for the software directly telling me not to follow it's advice).

Should I downvote the answer, because it is wrong? Should I modify my question to be more specific and THEN downvote the answer?

I'm planning on posting my own answer of what worked, but haven't done it yet.

Comment: If the answer is useful, you should upvote it. If the answer is not useful, you should downvote it. If you don't care about it, you shouldn't vote on it.

Comment: After you talking to support, you should now know how to do this.  So post the answer yourself.  You then get to choose whether your answer or the other answer is better :)

Comment: Update and then downvote: It sounds really unfair to downvote an answer which was forced to work with the limited amount of information you've provided in the first edition of the question (generally speaking). If you noticed that you missed some stuff in your question, then prefer to leave a comment for the answerer first, so he has a chance to update his answer according to the new information. If you feel that you question is already specific enough, then you _can_ downvote the answer if it isn't correct for you. But don't forget to tell him/her why it wasn't correct :).

Comment: Aside: That question as it stands does not seem to be a good fit on SO. SU, maybe?

Comment: There is a difference between a wrong answer and a bad answer.  DVs are for when the answer is not useful, wrong or has bad advice.  Since you did try it, it clearly was momentarily helpful.  Now, if the answer had described how to install a 5.25 inch floppy drive (or told you to re partition your boot drive), feel free to DV.  Keep in mind, in most cases people are trying to help.

Comment: "in my specific instance it is incorrect" - is it because you've asked different question than you should have? Asking new one (assuming it is on-topic, not the case for your current one) with link to original would be better option.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Keep in mind that the goal of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of great questions and answers. Answers can be useful without actually solving your original problem, so please don't downvote answers that are useful *just because* they didn't solve your issue. If you think the answer is *not useful*, or clearly missed the point, that's different.

I had a similar scenario [on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/169606/51900) - I eventually solved the problem myself, but another answer had lots of useful information in it, and actually helps more people than my solution to my less common cause (as evidenced by the upvotes it has received). Should I downvote it because it didn't actually resolve my issue? I would certainly not like to think so.

Probably controversial, but something else you might want to keep in mind: there is a tendency around here for people to say "it's only a downvote, get over it". And to a large extent that's correct and a lot of people probably could do with growing a thicker skin. However, for a lot of people, undeserved criticism is still going to sting. A downvote can feel like that, particularly if they have genuinely tried to help, provided information that is correct and potentially useful, and only failed to solve your issue because of some information that wasn't available to them at the time.

Comment: Where do you draw the line between being useful and completely missing the point? What if there's a good answer that is so far off that it could very well have been mistakenly posted to the wrong question? (*Edit* on second thought, probably a separate discussion.)

Comment: Good points - however this isn't a formula for exactly how to vote every time - it's still going to be a subjective process (which is what voting's all about though, right?) and where that line is drawn is ultimately going to be a personal choice unless we want to get more prescriptive on how to vote (which we probably don't). But I would say a good rule of thumb would be: *know it's useful* => upvote; *not sure* => don't vote; *definitely missing the point* => downvote (with comment). Personally I like to comment, wait a while and downvote if no improvement, but that's not very scalable.

Comment: I'm not sure you second point needs to be dealt with separately - ultimately the answer should be deleted by the answerer and reposted elsewhere, so downvotes will draw the answerer's attention, and automatically be reversed if and when they fix the problem.

Answer (score 25):

You are free to do with your votes what you wish, with the obvious caveat that you can't pick a user at random and vote on all of their stuff at once.

That said, if you personally feel that the answer wasn't helpful, then you may feel free to downvote it.  In this scenario I'd recommend leaving a comment as to why it wasn't *specifically* helpful to you, since others may pick it up and glean a lot of helpfulness from that answer later.

Comment: FWIW "vote on all of their stuff at once" [may be okay if...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210257/165773 "as explained here") "...if you're going to review them, do it right: up-vote the good stuff, down-vote the bad stuff, edit the stuff that should be edited, leave comments where you can do some good that way..."

Comment: @gnat the issue is that you can't be be sure you aren't voting based on the user rather than his content. And neither can the automated serial voting detection script.

Comment: @JanDvorak that's a good point - when you start you "user review" you can't really be sure if you end with all votes in one direction, and that would be serial. Because of that, I tweaked Shog's advice for my own use, so that I do such "review" only in case if I can see that user has posts that I can vote in opposite directions, up _and_ down. Sort of a proof for self that I'm not totally biased. This "test" may look weak but I almost always fail it (and as a result, abstain of voting the user)

Answer (score 6):

If I search in google/stackoverflow and get a result with a question that is LIKE (not equal) mine AND an answer solves MY problem then I upvote the question and the answer.

IMHO downvoting only makes sense if the answer is definitly wrong for your described problem (not for your real problem)... So I described a problem in the past and got answers which did not solve it - in my case.
Others had the "same" problem (problem description matched nearly 100%) and could solve their problem with this anser...

Comment: Very good point on "described" problem - what you post actually may not relate to what you need.