# Should I downvote an answer that does not answer the question asked?

Tags: discussion, voting

**Should I downvote an answer if it is not related to what the OP asked for?**

This question [How to get a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class) was asked. I'm both a Java and JavaScript developer and recently used the selected answer to this question.  So I have a pretty good idea of why the OP asked the question and I believe one of the answers was not what the OP asked for.  But this is my opinion, and I'm not sure I should downvote just because it's my opinion.

So I looked for guidance on Stack Overflow META and came up with reasons to support downvoting and reasons to just provide a comment.

**Reasons to downvote answer**

1. Based on [...generally correct, but is wrong for my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308129/should-i-downvote-an-answer-that-might-be-generally-correct-but-is-wrong-for-my) I
   could downvote because one comment says: "DVs are for when the
   answer is not useful, wrong or **has bad advice**."
2. A good rule of thumb is: know it's useful => upvote; not sure => don't vote; definitely missing the point => downvote (with comment).

**Reasons to not downvote (and perhaps leave a comment)**

1. Based on the guidance given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) I should not because the
   answer was not *clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect*.
2. [...Don't downvote answers that are useful just because they didn't
   solve your issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308129/should-i-downvote-an-answer-that-might-be-generally-correct-but-is-wrong-for-my)
3. The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of great questions
   and answers and that requires users.  New users can perceive a down
   vote as undeserved criticism and need guidance not criticism.

At this point I just provide a comment and look for responses to my question to see if I should downvote.

I just recently received the privilege to downvote and want to use that privilege wisely.

Comment: It depends. as always. but it's actually quite simple. Do you think the answer is useful? do you think it is high quality? upvote it. Do you think it isn't useful? low quality? downvote it. Votes are entirely subjective, they *should* be based on your opinion.

Comment: So basically, don't overthink it.  If I don't think the answer is useful (based on my opinion which is based on my experience) downvote and provide a comment and move on.  If I'm off base or wrong others will upvote it.

Comment: @PatS - You can comment, but it isn't required. Sometimes commenting leads to arguments which are tangential to the actual topic.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, I'd generally consider that "unhelpful" and worth a downvote.  Unless there are some other good insights or something to mitigate the fact that it doesn't work.

Comment: Downvote if you think the question as a whole is better without that answer. If you are downvoting in the face of many other up votes, you are really just sacrificing some rep for no reason and people wont even see your down vote unless they click on the vote count. A comment may encourage the op to edit their answer to address your concerns or direct future users to another answer.

Comment: Just don't vote to punish/reward/retaliate/comfort; vote only based on the content, don't vote based on people. If you stick to that, you can hardly go wrong really. Commenting is entirely optional, and not always a good idea. For advice to be taken, advice needs to be wanted.

Comment: "_Sometimes commenting leads to arguments which are tangential to the actual topic_" and sometimes it leads to worse, like revenge downvoting, so be very cautious of commenting.

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked numerous times before?

Comment: I had a professor in college who would give failing grades on essays that didn't answer the question regardless of how good the overall content was.

Comment: @Thomas Weller, Is it a duplicate?  Not that I found.   I refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308129/should-i-downvote-an-answer-that-might-be-generally-correct-but-is-wrong-for-my which was the closest to the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is the answer useful? Upvote

Everyone is going to have their own metrics for quantifying usefulness, and that's OK. It's also largely going to depend on the situation.

I have found answers that either provide a general solution to the problem while not necessarily being within the constraints imposed in the question, or completely misunderstand the question, that were more useful to me for one reason or another than the accepted answer to the question.

---

Is the answer not useful? Downvote

If the answer is just plain off-topic and doesn't make any sense in the given context, all it is ever going to do is confuse people. Downvote it to push it further to the bottom of the page and out of sight. If you have delete votes and the answer is eligible for deletion, cast a delete vote and get it gone.

Whatever you do, **don't flag it**. This is not what flags are for (unless a user has a habit of spamming off-topic answers to questions, but I imagine this is extremely rare).

---

Don't care? Don't vote.

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is pretty easy:

> If the answer doesn't answer the question asked: downvote

Even if you think the answer is useful for solving other problems and even if the answer has high quality, just downvote.

**An answer solving problem X does not belong in a question asking about Y.**

Sometimes the difficult part is that before you downvote, you need to be sure that the answer is really not an answer to the question. So if you are in doubt move on without a downvote  but don't upvote either.

Comment: also it's possible to upvote an answer which partially answers the question.